# Where is untyped_to_typed method?

Tags: f#

I'm learning to use F# to build WPF applications. I using [this](http://jyliao.blogspot.com/search/label/WPF) as reference. I'm stuck with this one example where the author is trying to

```
IEnumerable.untyped_to_typed
```

Its giving me a compile error. Is it being renamed or am I missing something?

Comment: *Always* post your error message :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that page is referencing previous versions of the `Seq` and `IEnumerable` modules.

Use `Seq.cast` instead.

Answer (score 0):

@vasu-balakrishnan The code you could use for this is:

```
//IEnumerable.untyped_to_typed grid.Children 
//|> IEnumerable.iter (fun (ctrl : Control) -> ctrl.Margin <- thick)
for child in grid.Children do
   (fun (child : Control) -> child.Margin <- thick) |> ignore
```